# Pandas Object Column with Mixed Types list and string - dowstream impact on explode

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-explode

I have a chunk of code that has worked for some time, and now, for some reason my use of `.explode` has stopped working as expected.  After doing some digging, it appears that while the values **look like lists of dicts**, some are shown as type strings, and other type lists.

Example data below.

Here I am printing out the type of the object column for the last 5 rows

```
4411     <class 'str'>
4412    <class 'list'>
4413    <class 'list'>
4414     <class 'str'>
4415     <class 'str'>
```

And with that shown, here is the data.  The column watchedSegments below is the column that I am looking to explode.  I have never come across this before where the values are list-like, but for some reason I don't understand, pandas thinks some are strings and others are lists.

```
            id                 watchedSegments
4411  12559466       [{"start":0,"end":17.04}]
4412  12559947  [{'end': 2645.39, 'start': 0}]
4413  12560180  [{'end': 1062.17, 'start': 0}]
4414  12560397        [{"start":0,"end":1.42}]
4415  12560861     [{"start":0,"end":1242.95}]
```

Pandas `.explode('watchedSegments')` yields

```
>>> views_tmp.tail().explode('watchedSegments')
            id               watchedSegments
4411  12559466     [{"start":0,"end":17.04}]
4412  12559947  {'end': 2645.39, 'start': 0}
4413  12560180  {'end': 1062.17, 'start': 0}
4414  12560397      [{"start":0,"end":1.42}]
4415  12560861   [{"start":0,"end":1242.95}]
>>>
```

and the data exported with `to_dict`

```
>>> views_tmp.tail().to_dict()
{'id': {4411: 12559466, 4412: 12559947, 4413: 12560180, 4414: 12560397, 4415: 12560861}, 'watchedSegments': {4411: '[{"start":0,"end":17.04}]', 4412: [{'end': 2645.39, 'start': 0}], 4413: [{'end': 1062.17, 'start': 0}], 4414: '[{"start":0,"end":1.42}]', 4415: '[{"start":0,"end":1242.95}]'}}
>>>
```

My question.

Is there a way to ensure that the `object` column type `watchedSegments` is always of type `<class 'list'>`?

Comment: can you provied `df.tail(5).to_dict()` after drop useless columns?

Comment: I ran a net set of data to ensure I wasn't going crazy, so I updated above and also included your dict representation @PandaKim

Comment: What does the `watchedSegments` look like in original dataset/file? What transformations did you apply to create `watchedSegments` column? Can you reproduce it on a toy example?

Comment: No transformations applied, the original data included that list of dicts for for each row, watchedSegments.

Answer (score 2):

```
views_tmp.tail().to_dict()
```

output :

```
{'id': {4411: 12559466,
  4412: 12559947,
  4413: 12560180,
  4414: 12560397,
  4415: 12560861},
 'watchedSegments': {4411: '[{"start":0,"end":17.04}]',  <-- str becuz exist ' before [ 
  4412: [{'end': 2645.39, 'start': 0}],        <-- list nothing before [
  4413: [{'end': 1062.17, 'start': 0}],        <-- list
  4414: '[{"start":0,"end":1.42}]',            <-- str
  4415: '[{"start":0,"end":1242.95}]'}}        <-- str
```

your data has list or string like list, so your result like following:

```
4411     <class 'str'>
4412    <class 'list'>
4413    <class 'list'>
4414     <class 'str'>
4415     <class 'str'>
```

---

**Solution**

make provided dict by you to dataframe for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(views_tmp.tail().to_dict())
```

use following code:

```
out = df['watchedSegments'].astype('str').apply(eval).str[0]
```

`out`:

```
4411      {'start': 0, 'end': 17.04}
4412    {'end': 2645.39, 'start': 0}
4413    {'end': 1062.17, 'start': 0}
4414       {'start': 0, 'end': 1.42}
4415    {'start': 0, 'end': 1242.95}
Name: watchedSegments, dtype: object
```

chk dtype of `out` cells

```
out.map(type)
```

output:

```
4411    <class 'dict'>
4412    <class 'dict'>
4413    <class 'dict'>
4414    <class 'dict'>
4415    <class 'dict'>
Name: watchedSegments, dtype: object
```

Comment: `eval` is a the solution I was looking for. Thanks!. +1 for that.